# Searching through HTML tables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an html table with paginations. is there any script i could use to search through the entire table. 
The script below only searches the current page.

PS: I could also use datatables but then i want to know if there are other simple scripts to use

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  // Declare variables 
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("table");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    } 
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: How are your pages generated?  Server-side?  Hiding rows?

Comment: That means that you need to either query your database and rebuild your view or have access to the full table data and reinitialize your pagination plugin over the filtered data subset.

Comment: @freedomn-m , server side and then i also paginate with my controllers. I am using laravel framework

Comment: So, essentially, the data is not available for you to run javascript against.  You have to make another call to the server to get the data to apply the filter to.  So you might as well apply all your filtering and paging on the server side.